# WebView and MathML

Tags: android, webview, mathml

I have tried putting MathML code into a WebView and it doesn't render properly. What am I doing incorrectly?

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebView;

public class HelloWebView extends Activity {
WebView mWebView;
String mathml = "<html><body><math xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML\"><mrow><msup> <mi>x</mi> <mn>2</mn> </msup></mrow></math> END OF TEST</body></html>";

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mWebView.loadData(mathml, "text/html", "utf-8");
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

String mathml used MathML tags. WebView cannot render MathML tags. I tried using MathJax but it needs 16MB of files to render mathematical equations. I don't how MathJax can be used in Android given it's size.

Comment: If your application have internet access you can use their CDN. I use CDN to avoid bulky APK and onlne version works great.

Answer (score 1):

You should look at MathJax (www.mathjax.org). Its a JavaScript engine for displaying MathML. In fact, it is used to display math in StackExchange.

Comment: IPython use Mathjax in their Notebook too, and it works really nicely.

Answer (score 0):

```
loadDataWithBaseURL("http://bar",
                "<html><head>" +
                        " <meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"width=device-width, user-scalable=yes\" />" +
                        "</head>" +
                        "" +
                        "<body style=\"font-size:18px\" >" +
                        text +
                        "<script type=\"text/x-mathjax-config\">" +
                        "  MathJax.Hub.Config({\n" +
                        "  CommonHTML: { linebreaks: { automatic: true },EqnChunk:(MathJax.Hub.Browser.isMobile?10:50) },displayAlign: \"left\",\n" +
                        "  \"HTML-CSS\": { linebreaks: { automatic: true } ," +
                        "\n" +
                        "    preferredFont: \"STIX\"}," +
                        "extensions: [\"tex2jax.js\"],messageStyle:\"none\"," +
                        "jax: [\"input/TeX\", \"input/MathML\",\"output/HTML-CSS\"]," +
                        "tex2jax: {inlineMath: [['$','$'],['\\\\(','\\\\)']]}" +
                        "});" +
                        "</script>" +
                        "<script type=\"text/javascript\" async src=\"file:///android_asset/MathJax/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML\"></script>" +
                        "" +
                        "</body>" +
                        "</html>", "text/html", "utf-8", "");

        loadUrl("javascript:MathJax.Hub.Queue(['Typeset',MathJax.Hub]);");
```

Comment: You need to  put this code for loading mathml with MathJax.  https://www.mathjax.org/

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. [Edit] those information in your question.